# Changing qdisc algorithm sysctl and tc

Tags: networking, kernel, network-interface

What qdisc is controlled via the `tc` command versus `sysctl net.core.default_qdisc`?  Consider

```
$ tc qdisc show dev eth2
qdisc mq 0: dev eth2 root 

$ sysctl net.core.default_qdisc
net.core.default_qdisc = pfifo_fast
```

On this system, the default qdisc is set to *pfifo_fast* but the qdisc in use is *mq* (Multi-queue) after a reboot.  It's rather obvious that they are not directly related, or at the least, not in a manner which makes sense "out of the box".  [This link](https://www.coverfire.com/articles/queueing-in-the-linux-network-stack/) about queuing in the Linux Network Stack makes it clear that `tc qdisc ...` applies to the *Queue* which sits between the IP Stack and the Driver Queue.

Can anyone disambiguate these two for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiqueue ("mq") scheduler enables the Linux kernel to support a feature called Receive-Side-Scaling (RSS) where the load for packet processing is distributed across multiple CPU cores.

On my Ubuntu 18.04.1 Desktop system with net.core.default_qdisc set to pfifo_fast and I execute the following command:

```
$ tc qdisc show dev eth0
```

This is what is output:

```
qdisc mq 0: root
qdisc pfifo_fast 0: parent :2 bands 3 priomap  1 2 2 2 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
qdisc pfifo_fast 0: parent :1 bands 3 priomap  1 2 2 2 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

The mq scheduler has configured two pfifo_fast queues on device eth0 by default.

Hope this clears things up.